# Wait for a child process for no longer than X seconds

Tags: c, fork

I want to fork() a child process then call execl() to replace the child's process image with a new process that might not stop (will get stuck in a while loop or will expect input where it shouldn't for example).
I want to wait for it for no longer than X seconds.
It should look something like that:

```
int main() {

    pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid==-1) {
        perror("fork() error");
    }
    else if (pid==0) {
        //call execlp("exe.out","exe.out",arg1, ... ,NULL)
        //where exe.out might not stop at all
    }
    else {
        //wait for X seconods, and if child process didn't terminate
        //after X seconds have passed, terminate it
    }
}
```

wait() and waitpid() does not provide this capability.
How can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: `waitpid()` has a `WNOHANG` flag that allows you to test whether the child has exited without blocking.

Comment: It seems like there should be an easier way to do this, but a `SIGCHLD` signal handler can be installed which will notify you when a child has exited, so you can install a signal handler which will notify your main thread of execution through a pipe, and then your main code path would wait in a `select` on the receiving end of the pipe with a timeout.

Comment: Hi @PP., thanks for the comment. the Linux manual page says that if i set WNOHANG it will "return immediately if no child has exited". where can I specify X seconds?

Comment: @mkimball Linux has the easier way: [signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)

Comment: Kudos to @WumpusQ.Wumbley; just for the record, the original idea comes from http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html, and it should work on any unix.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a signal handler alarm to go off after X seconds and then do your wait(2). If the wait returns, the child state changed before X seconds. If the signal handler returns, no child state change.

Don't forget to reset the alarm should the wait(2) return.

Comment: Hi @mpez0, thanks for the help. To be honest, I have no idea what signal handler alarm is (probably something that we didn't learn in our course yet), but I just found out that there is sleep() system call. can it work in some way?

Comment: Sleep (chapter 3) as a library function is usually implemented using the alarm(chapter 2) system call. You need a little more functionality than sleep(3) alone offers, and you can do it using alarm(2) or signal(2). You can simplify matters by using sleep(3) to wait X seconds and then do the waitpid(2) with NOHANG, but you'll always get that X second pause. If that's a good tradeoff for you now, do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create one more child that kills `pid` process if it doesn't receive a signal from the parent that `pid` process ended before timeout (in pseudocode):

```
in_, out = pipe()
pid2 = fork()
if pid2 != 0: # parent
   close(in_)
   waitpid(pid, 0) # wait for child to complete
   write(out, b'1') # signal to pid2 child to abort the killing
   waitpid(pid2, 0)
else: # child
   close(out)
   ready, _, _ = select([in_], [], [], timeout) # wait `timeout` seconds
   if not ready: # timeout
      kill(pid, SIGTERM)
      write(2, b"kill child")
   else:
      write(2, b"child ended before timeout")
   _exit(0)
```

Here's [complete code example](http://ideone.com/7tqA2R).

On Linux, it is implemented as [`eventfd(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html).